# how to install Mongo DB 4.4.0 on Red Hat 8.4?

Tags: mongodb, server, redhat

tried to get specific **.rpm** package for mongo database for Red hat 8 but cannot find to 4.4.0 version
`yum install mongodb 4.4.0`
but cannot get the packages for this

Comment: Follow this: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Red Hat or CentOS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 4 is available on MongoDB yum repository. Add the repository to your RHEL 8 server by running below commands:

```
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.repo<<EOF
[mongodb-org-4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/8/mongodb-org/4.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
EOF
```

You need to run the commands above as user with sudo privileges.
Once the repo has been added, install mongodb-org package.

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

the result should be:

```
$ rpm -qi mongodb-org-server
  Name        : mongodb-org-server
  Version     : 4.4.8
  Release     : 1.el8
```